# can I access store proprieties in shopify

Tags: python, shopify

can I access store proprieties in shopify (not mine) like launch date, email etc. similar to data that is available at /admin/api/2019-04/shop.json
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/store-properties/shop

I tried  /shop.json but it returns the original html of home page not json format with data

Comment: What does (not mine) means ? Access Shopify store properties of a store that you don't have admin access or API credentials ? - It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been granted API access to the shop by requesting it with some scopes, then you can see the same values as an admin hitting the shop.json endpoint by asking for the shop information at the shop endpoint.

Comment: I do not  understand what requesting it with some scopes means, will that require admin permission? thanks

Comment: You have to ask for permission to see orders, products, etc. Scopes... anything API related requires permissions. 

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes